# How do I make a simple password page with multiple passwords?

Tags: javascript, html, password-protection

I want to create a simple page where the user can type in different passwords that leads to different pages. One password is "dogs" and leads to a dog page. One password is "cats" and leads to a cats page etc. Basically multiple password from one password field.

Here's what I got so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="pswd">Enter your password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="pswd">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkPswd();" />
</form>
<!--Function to check password the already set password is dogs-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
        var confirmPassword = "dogs";
        var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
             window.location="dogs.html";
        }
        else{
            alert("Passwords do not match.");
        }
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is for dogs.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dogs page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!! you entered the DOGS password</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it looks like a good start.

Comment: why not have a map from passwords to urls, then on click can see if its in map and nav to url if so

Comment: If you want actual password protection, you need to implement it in the backend.

Comment: People can just use CTRL+U or Inspect (CTRL+SHIFT+I) to see the password, you want to use a backend language like PHP, and then send the request to a page called "login.php" which processes the login. Plus, anyone can just go to dogs.html anyway since there is no proper password protection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115719/easy-way-to-password-protect-php-page

Comment: If you really need to store passwords in the frontend, store them hashed and then hash the form input in the backend, and check the newly hashed input against the already hashed password. You can hash with `password_hash()` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not how you safely store passwords. Anyone that has access to your website will have access to all possible passwords.**

Here is a nice way you might go about doing this. You could have an array of objects representing each page/password. When a user enters a password, the function will look for the object that matches in the array, and will return the  page. If it doesn't exist, your alert will popup.

```
const passwords = [
    {
        pass: "dogs",
        page: "dogs"
    },
    {
        pass: "cats",
        page: "cats"
    },
    {
        pass: "anotherpassword",
        page: "secretpage"
    }
];

function checkPswd() {
    const passInput = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
    const passMatch = passwords.find(o => o.pass === passInput);
  
    if (passMatch ) {
        console.log(`Redirecting to: "${passMatch.page}"`);
        window.location = `${passMatch.page}.html`;
    } else {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing passwords on frontend defeats the purpose of passwords.

Comment: I had assumed the app was supposed to be very simple and not include any backend encryption or anything.

Comment: I get it but some people will blindly copy this thinking it protects anything.